# Error on export to PDF with Maatwebsite

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf, maatwebsite-excel

I want to export to PDF in Laravel 5.5 with [maatwebsite/laravel-excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel). When I try to export to excel it works. But when I export to PDF I get this error:

> *Unable to load PDF Rendering library*

I've tried to change the entry in `composer.json` from `"dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.1"` to `"dompdf/dompdf": "0.6.2"` without success.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-excel is deprecated.

You should use **snappy** https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy with **wkhtmltopdf** https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: Hardly looks deprecated.